# How to use the %username% in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have been trying to get the below script to work with the current user that's logged on:

```
On Error Resume Next

Set oFileSys = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sRoot = "C:\users\MyUsername\downloads"
today = Date
nMaxFileAge = 30
DeleteFiles(sRoot)

Function DeleteFiles(ByVal sFolder)
    Set oFolder = oFileSys.GetFolder(sFolder)
    Set aFiles = oFolder.Files
    Set aSubFolders = oFolder.SubFolders

    For Each file in aFiles
        dFileCreated = FormatDateTime(file.DateCreated, "2")
        If DateDiff("d", dFileCreated, today) > nMaxFileAge Then
            file.Delete(True)
        End If
    Next

    For Each folder in aSubFolders
        DeleteFiles(folder.Path)
    Next
End Function
```

Now this works fine when I specifically define the "MyUsername" part of `sRoot=`, but I want this to be a variable. I have tried many suggestions in other posts but just can't seem to get this to work.

I'm going to deploy this to a few machines on startup that have different users so that's why it needs to be a variable as I don't know who will be logged into those computers at any given time.

Comment: I have finally found the answer in this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258165/how-to-get-a-path-with-the-variable-user-in-vbscript

Answer (score 0):

From Help

> Returns an environment variable's expanded value.
>
> ### object.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strString)
>
> ```
> object
> ```
>
> *WshShell object.*
>
> ```
> str
> ```
>
> *String*
>
> *String value indicating the name of the environment variable you want to expand.*
>
> The `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` method expands environment variables
>   defined in the PROCESS environment space only. Environment variable
>   names, which must be enclosed between "%" characters, are not
>   case-sensitive.
>
> The following code expands the Windows Directory environment variable
>   and displays it:
>
> **Visual Basic Script**
>
> ```
> set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
> WScript.Echo "WinDir is " & WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WinDir%")
> ```

***The preferred way is to***

> Returns the name of a user.
>
> ```
> object.UserName 
>
> object
> ```
>
> *WshNetwork object.*
>
> ```
> *Returns a string.*
> ```
>
> If you are using this property in a login script, see Creating an
>   Automated Login Script.
>
> The following example demonstrates the use of the UserName property:
>
> ```
>      Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
>      WScript.Echo "Domain = " & WshNetwork.UserDomain
>      WScript.Echo "Computer Name = " & WshNetwork.ComputerName
>      WScript.Echo "User Name = " & WshNetwork.UserName
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the answer in the following article:

[How to get a path with the variable user in VBscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258165/how-to-get-a-path-with-the-variable-user-in-vbscript)

In short for anyone else needing this, here is the corrected code (for my example):

```
On Error Resume Next

Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
userprofile = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")

Set oFileSys = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sRoot = userprofile & "\downloads"                  
today = Date                                            
nMaxFileAge = 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure what you posted here ? debug your code first by getting rid from `On Error Resume Next` and correct your code !

Comment: Yes I am sure, why else would I have said "I discovered the answer"?

Comment: Ok !, so you are sure ! ? Can you explain me what's the meaning of this `***` in the above code that you discoverd ?

Comment: Hello Hackoo, good question, I have no idea. I fixed it now because I see where this was causing confusion. My bad...